# How to retrieve Azure Active Directory Settings Key value from Angular 5

Tags: angular, active-directory, azure-active-directory

My application has an API KEY that it uses to communicate with another server (not active directory).  I want Azure Active Directory to supply that API KEY to the application when someone uses Azure Active Directory to log in.

I've tried to do this by adding a key in the `API ACCESS` section of Azure Active Directory (Navigate to Azure Active Directory -> App registrations -> click on app name -> Settings -> Keys).  It has a description of `myappToken` with an expiration 2 years from now and a hidden value.

I'm connecting to Azure Active directory using `adal` and `Adal5Service` in my Angular 5 application.  I get a lot of information back from the login including clientId, loginResource, tenant, user information (name, id, token, exp, etc), but I don't see the `myappToken` in the return anywhere.  Is there a way to retrieve this?

Is there a different way to add additional information to Azure Active Directory that I want to return to my application (ie: api keys, secrets, additional user information)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to retrieve `myappToken` (key) by API? A key represents a client secret  which is used in client-credential (client-grant) flow of application authentication scenario. You can refer to this [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds) for detail. Once a key is generated, it can not be **retrieved** and marked as `hidden`. 
If you have lost the key then a new key should be generated and used in the downstream applications for authentication.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  My application has an API KEY that it uses to communicate with another server (not active directory).  I want Azure Active Directory to supply that API KEY to the application when someone uses Azure Active Directory to log in.

Comment: Then in that case, you should store your secret to `Azure Key Vault` which is meant to store the secret. Application registration is meant to store the details required by an application for various Azure Authentication flow.